# Deploy kolla-ansible OpenStask wuth LDAP integration

Tags: openstack, keystone, openstack-horizon

Please tell me how deploy OpenStack with Ansible Kolla with LDAP integration.

Comment: That depends on your environment. You could take a look at the documentation regarding the integration of LDAP with keystone [here](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/wallaby/admin/configuration.html#integrate-identity-with-ldap).

Comment: I have already read this document and tried it. This does not work when deployed via kolla-ansible.
I added to file /etc/kolla/config/keystone/keystone.conf
`[identity]
driver = ldap
[ldap]
url = ldap://ipa.site.ru
user = uid=keystone,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=site,dc=ru
password = mysercetpass
....`
And trying to deploy new OpenStask multinode cluster
then the error occurs at the task "Creating admin project, user, role, service, and endpoint"
https://github.com/openstack/kolla-ansible/blob/master/ansible/roles/keystone/tasks/register.yml#L2

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but was searching for the answer to this as well and ended up solving it.

You will need to create domain-specific configuration for LDAP authentication. This way you leave your default domain and projects alone with their built-in authentication and you will have a separate domain with all your projects that authenticate with LDAP.

Create a custom config file referencing your `${your_domain_name}` in `/etc/kolla/config/keystone/domains/keystone.${your_domain_name}.conf`

Then in that file you set your driver to LDAP and define all your required LDAP configuration parameters as referenced in https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/admin/configuration.html

```
[identity]
driver=ldap

[ldap]

# Your LDAP config settings go here
```

That is all you need to configure before deployment. After running
the `deploy` and `post-deploy` jobs in Kolla,  source the `/etc/kolla/admin-openrc.sh` file to get the admin credentials and create your domain that will authenticate with LDAP via the CLI:

```
openstack domain create ${your_domain_name}
```

After restarting the Keystone container, it should now have connected that domain to LDAP which can be confirmed via the CLI:

```
openstack user list --domain ${your_domain_name}
```